# What does (Comparator<T> & Serializable) means?

Tags: java, casting, comparator

Today I came to this code in Comparator class on java 15.

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

I'd like to understand what this means  `(Comparator<T> & Serializable)`. Is it a Casting?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16